# SQL query with 200+ Where criteria is too complex (Access 2013)

Tags: sql, ms-access

So I've never worked with SQL before, pretty much everything I know is from playing around with Access's Query Designer and then looking at the resulting SQL code. So I'm pretty sure that I'm not doing this efficiently.

Here's the skinny:

-I have a database called "SPC Data" that has measured data for each component on each circuit board that we build.

-I want to write one SQL query that will fetch around 500 rows based on combinations of barcodes and component data.

-The query is built dynamically in a VBA macro elsewhere, and this is what it looks like now:

```
SELECT *
FROM [SPC Data]
WHERE ((([SPC Data].Barcode)=1504803581) AND (([SPC Data].[Component ID]) Like '*R56')) OR 
((([SPC Data].Barcode)=1433700392) AND (([SPC Data].[Component ID]) Like '*C15')) OR 
((([SPC Data].Barcode)=1433700664) AND (([SPC Data].[Component ID]) Like '*R56')) OR 
((([SPC Data].Barcode)=1433700486) AND (([SPC Data].[Component ID]) Like '*R56')) OR
... about 220 more lines of criteria
```

I feel like this shouldn't be too memory-intensive, but Access complains that the Query is too Complex unless I pare the query down to only around 60 Or'd criteria (might work with more, this was just a random value that worked).

My question is this: why won't my SQL execute? Am I writing the SQL in a way that is making it inefficient and overly complex for Access? Is there a better way to select a bunch of matched pairs of criteria? Or should I just split it into multiple SQL queries, with ~60 criteria each? I'll be grateful for any direction on this.

**Update (1 hour later):** I still don't have a robust solution; Unions didn't help so I'm guessing this is an Access issue. I can try making a temporary table of the records I need and then joining it with the original to get all of my column data as DRapp suggested, or I could just split the SQL and import them 60 at a time. I was hoping there was some obvious mistake that I was making.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that the suggestion to use the "IN" clause would work for you as what if your barcode can be applicable to multiple component IDs?  Not sure, but possible?

What you might be better at getting a solution is to create a secondary table and insert into that all the things you are looking for,  then do you join to that.  Not exactly, but the principle as:

```
create table tmpJoin( tryBarCode  integer, tryComponent varchar(5))

insert into tmpJoin ( tryBarCode, tryComponent ) values ( 1504803581, '*R56' )
insert into tmpJoin ( tryBarCode, tryComponent ) values ( 1433700392, '*C15')
insert into tmpJoin ( tryBarCode, tryComponent ) values ( 1433700664, '*R56')
insert into tmpJoin ( tryBarCode, tryComponent ) values ( 1433700486, '*R56')
etc for as many things as you are looking for...
```

Now,  the query...

```
SELECT 
      sd.*
   FROM 
      [SPC Data] sd
         JOIN tmpJoin 
            on sd.barcode = tmpJoin.tryBarCode
            AND sd.[Component ID] like tmpJoin.tryComponent
```

So, if you have 1 or 1000 entries in the tmpJoin, your query doesn't get any longer.  It just finds a match or it doesn't and returns the row from your SPC Data table

Of course, you would need to have an index on the tmpJoin table for query optimization, and either delete/recreate during each search or create new random table name and delete when done so if multiple people running query, it does not cause conflict... other options like adding a column to identify a unique new person's query and deleting those records when finished running the query.

Comment: What about the IN does not work?  If barcode is applicable to more than one componentID then it is simply in another in.

Comment: @Blam, the issue is the person is specifically looking for a given ID AND Component likeness.  So, if ID = 123 is desired but only if like "*ABC", then the do not want a record if ID = 123 and component is 'XYZ'.  Your generic "IN" clause that would include 123 would be a false answer to their desired resultset.  But do see your prequalification of condition code first PLUS the IDs.    I still think that approach for so many possibilities would be too complex for Access to deal with.

Comment: What?  If they don't want ID 123  with component  'XYZ' then don't put 123 in the in.  You do notice 1433700392 is not in the example in with *R56?  An IN is certainly not more complex than an OR.

Comment: @Blam, although I partially DO agree with you on your setup of IN WITH The component id type as one criteria or'd with another, get to the original context of his question.  What to do when you have 200+ criteria.  You would be choking the IN () qualifier as even that is a limited list capacity.

Comment: Where do you get that IN has a max capacity?   I have had over 1000.  It is more efficient than multiple OR.  I will bet dollars to donuts the complexity limit is on number of OR.  For sure it reduces the size of query and there is a query size limit.

Comment: This one looks promising and would be easy to generate in VBA, I'll play around with it and let you know. Multiple people messing with the database is luckily not a concern, since the database is generated, queried, and discarded over the course of my program. Blam do you know what the query size limit is and if that may be what is preventing me from running my version in the original question?

Comment: Do you know that what I suggest is smaller?  You have not even tested because you are not *convinced* it will work.

Comment: I'm not testing it because it would require a complete re-write of my VBA code. I think you're also overestimating its effect on the size; my example had three barcodes with the same component, but that rarely happens. It was just a coincidence since at the beginning of the job there must have been some issue with our solder deposition or placement on that pad. Finally, in the future I'm going to add pins, which will make it statistically unlikely that ANY defect barcodes will share components and pins. I'm ignoring your solution for good reasons, it's just hard to explain over the internet.

Comment: @DRapp sorry, I was talking to Blam in that comment. Your solution is plausible for me, I'm going to try it hopefully before the end of the day.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it will help with the "too complex"  but you don't nee all those ( )

Looks like some of the like repeat
This might help with complexity and it will probably be faster
Like Like '* is very slow - you want to minimize those evaluation
Index on a Like '* does not good as it is a table scan

```
( [SPC Data].[Component ID] Like '*R56' 
  and [SPC Data].[Barcode] in (1504803581,1433700664,1433700486)  )  or 
( [SPC Data].[Component ID] Like '*C15' 
  and [SPC Data].[Barcode] in (1433700392)  )...
```

Comment: If I were writing it by hand that would likely be more efficient, but the SQL is dynamically generated in such a way that it would be difficult to use In(), if not infeasible. The best way to think about each AND criteria is as a unique identifier for a row in "SPC Data," grouping them would get messy.

Comment: So messy to write.  It is not infeasible.  If it works it works.  On the union answer you asked about speed.  This will be faster.  Like '* is slow - you want to minimize that.

Comment: Currently I need the '*' for reasons that are difficult to explain, but it's good to know that it slows down the query. In the future I'll be able to take it out.

I'm sure your code will be a bit faster, but it will significantly slow down the VBA code that generates the SQL, and make the VBA much more difficult to read and debug. One of the main deliverables for this project is that the code be readable and easily debugged by someone other than myself, so I'm willing to sacrifice some speed to that end. It also doesn't solve my issue since it could still become too complex for a large job.

Comment: So you need the * for good reasons.  You don't need to evaluate the   * multiple times.  Proper code to generate that syntax should not be slow or too complex to debug.  So in becomes too complex and you have to break the in up into unions. That is still way faster than more unions. You asked how to do that more efficiently and that is the proper answer.

Comment: Really what I'm asking is how to get it to execute without throwing an error. If efficiency is the answer I'm interested, but I'm not looking to _maximize_ the efficiency of the SQL. I'm not convinced that the wildcards are preventing the SQL from executing.

I suppose I may have confused you by questioning the speed of Pat's answer, but that's only because I concerned about the runtime of the query increasing linearly with the number of unions.

Comment: Not convinced - you don't know until you test.  The stated question is "Am I writing the SQL in a way that is making it inefficient and overly complex? Is there a better way to select a bunch of matched pairs of criteria?"  That is an answer to the stated question.

Comment: I've edited my question to be more clear, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, You could try using UNION or UNION ALL
Secondly, select only the fields you need 
Third, I would use another database other than MS-Acces.

```
SELECT * FROM [SPC Data]
WHERE [SPC Data].[Barcode]=1504803581 AND [SPC Data].[Component ID] Like '*R56'
UNION 
[SPC Data].[Barcode]=1433700664 AND [SPC Data].[Component ID] Like '*C15'
...
...
```

It will look a lot cleaner and easier to debug.

Comment: I though about using Union, but wouldn't that make the query significantly slower since it has to run through the database once for each union? Regardless I'll try that now and get back to you. I do need all of the fields unfortunately, and MS Access is necessary because I'm utilizing macros and an ADODB connection between excel and access.

Comment: Pat, I tried this code for union (it wasn't accepting the syntax of your snippet) and it works, but I imagine it would be twice as slow. So far, my best bet is probably to create separate select statements with 60 criteria each, and then union them.

`SELECT *
FROM [SPC Data]
WHERE [SPC Data].[Barcode]=1504803581 AND [SPC Data].[Component ID] Like '*R56'
UNION
SELECT *
FROM [SPC Data]
WHERE [SPC Data].[Barcode]=1433700664 AND [SPC Data].[Component ID] Like '*C15';`

Comment: Yep, go ahead and try it... It think it will be ok. I have used the Union in cases I had no choice for large volumes and it worked fine.For better performance, use UNION ALL if you don't expect duplicates.

Comment: Okay, I believe I haven't been using indexes, I'll try that with Union All on and see how it runs on a full query. I'll update this with my findings. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I recommend you create a primary key on your barcode and an index on Component ID.

Comment: Access can't utilize an index for `[Component ID] Like '*C15'`

Comment: I would extract the *C15 values and store it in a new column called ComponentFamily and store C15 in it. For compoents with '*R56' store 'R56' then index the field ComponentFamily and use it in the UNION ALL selects like this    SELECT * FROM [SPC Data]
WHERE [SPC Data].[Barcode]=1504803581 AND [SPC Data].[ComponentFamily] = 'R56'
UNION 
[SPC Data].[Barcode]=1433700664 AND [SPC Data].[ComponentFamily] Like = 'C15'